# OpenCV Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unrecognized or unsupported array type) in cvGetMat

Tags: c++, opencv, visualization

When I am trying to comment out the cvtColor function from my code I am getting the following error:
"OpenCV Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unrecognized or unsupported array type) in cvGetMat"

If I am using the cvtColor function then the program runs just fine.

I am trying to comment it out because I want the original color frame and not grayed out. 
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "opencv2/video/tracking.hpp"
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

float MHI_DURATION = 0.05;                
int DEFAULT_THRESHOLD = 10;

void draw_motion_comp(Mat& img, int x_coordinate, int y_coordinate, int width, int height);

Mat frame;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    namedWindow("Motion_tracking",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    char fileName[100] = "C:\\Users\\survya\\Downloads/VASTChallenge2009-M3-VIDEOPART1 (1).mov";  
    VideoCapture cap(fileName);

    if ( !cap.read(frame) )  // if not success, exit program
    {
        cout << "Cannot open the video file" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    Mat frame,ret,frame_diff,gray_diff,motion_mask;

    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        cap.read(frame);
        Size frame_size = frame.size();
        int h = frame_size.height;
        int w = frame_size.width;
        if(i==5)
            break;

    }

    ret = frame.clone();
    Size frame_size = frame.size();
    int h = frame_size.height;
    int w = frame_size.width;
    Mat prev_frame = frame.clone();
    Mat motion_history(h,w, CV_32FC1,Scalar(0,0,0));
    Mat seg_mask(h,w, CV_32FC1,Scalar(0,0,0));
    vector<Rect> seg_bounds;
    Mat vis(h,w,CV_32FC3);
    Mat vis1(h,w,CV_8UC1);
    while(1)
    {
        cap.retrieve(frame);
        cap.read(frame);
        ret = frame.clone();
        if (!ret.data) //if not success, break loop
        {
            cout << "video ended" << endl;
            break;
        } 
        absdiff(frame, prev_frame, frame_diff);

        //cvtColor(frame_diff,gray_diff, CV_BGR2GRAY); //want to comment this line out but getting the error stated in my question

        threshold(gray_diff,ret,DEFAULT_THRESHOLD,255,0);
        motion_mask = ret.clone();
        double timestamp = 1000.0*clock()/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        updateMotionHistory(motion_mask, motion_history, timestamp, MHI_DURATION);          
        segmentMotion(motion_history, seg_mask, seg_bounds, timestamp, 32);

            vis = frame.clone();
            vis = frame_diff.clone();   

            for(int i=0; i< motion_history.cols; i++)
                {
                    for(int j=0; j< motion_history.rows ; j++)
                    { 
                    float a = motion_history.at<float>(j,i);                
                    if((a-timestamp-MHI_DURATION)/MHI_DURATION <= -5)
                        vis1.at<uchar>(j,i) = 0;
                    else
                        vis1.at<uchar>(j,i) = (a-timestamp-MHI_DURATION)/MHI_DURATION;
                    }
                }

            cvtColor(vis1,vis,COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

        for(unsigned int h = 0; h < seg_bounds.size(); h++)
                {
                    Rect rec = seg_bounds[h];
                    if(rec.area() > 5000 && rec.area() < 70000)
                    {
                        rectangle(vis, rec,Scalar(0,0,255),2);      
                    }               
                }   
        imshow("Motion_tracking",vis);      
        prev_frame = frame.clone();
            if(waitKey(30) >= 0) //wait for 'esc' key press for 30ms. If 'esc' key is pressed, break loop
        {
            cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl;
            break; 
        }
    }   

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because, if you comment out that line:

1. you never assign a value to `gray_diff`, so the following `threshold` function will work on an invalid matrix, and
2. when you compute the `absdiff`, `frame` and `prev_frame` are of type `CV_8UC3`, and so will be also the result `frame_diff`. But `threshold` expects an input of type `CV_8UC1`. So you need to convert `frame_diff` to single channel `gray_diff` in order to work on it with `threshold`.

So, here you *need* to use `cvtColor`, and I don't see any reason why you want to remove it.

Comment: I want to remove it because I want the code to run on the original colored video instead of a black and white video. Any idea how I can do it if using cvtColor is mandatory?

Comment: You **are** working on a color video. The difference mask however is, and should be, a single channel image, since a mask is by definition a binary image. It's hard to understand what you want to do, and it's probably _too broad_ to be discussed here. This answer addresses the problem stated to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,
just add the `cv::Mat frame` inside the `while()` loop

Comment: Please add some explanation. Why do you think your proposed solution might help the OP?

Comment: the matrix of each frame was being created outside the loop. Therefore, outside the loop it is as if it had not been declared.